# libevent stops working after a few thousand calls

Tags: c, linux, libevent

Below is my initialization code from the main()

```
evthread_use_pthreads();

struct event_config *cfg = event_config_new();
event_config_require_features(cfg, EV_FEATURE_EARLY_CLOSE);
c->base = event_base_new_with_config(cfg);
event_config_free(cfg);
```

I then start dispatch loop from a thread

```
int rv = event_base_dispatch(c->base);
//rv = event_base_loop(c->base, EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY);
```

i then use bufferevent_socket_new as needed and this works for a long time. However, after a few thousand bufferevent_socket_new and closing them, event_base_dispatch suddenly stops working and exits with return value 1.

Any further calls to event_base_dispatch() returns 1 immediately and then nothing works.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Note that system works fine for a few thousand bufferevent socket calls.

Comment: I believe a return value of 1 means that no events are registered.

Comment: most likely not freeing some resource